# Is it possible to build GraphQL query where the second part of the query depends on the result of the first one?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I have a setup where I run a query on the frontend through the router (Apollo Federation Gateway) to two separate services exposing GQL endpoints - serviceA has `findItems` and serviceB has `parseName`.

Now I want to run the following query in one go:

```
query findMyItemDescriptionNameAndParse {
  findItems(id: 1) {
    description {
      name
    }
  }
  parseName(input: $name) {
     parsedName {
        name
     }
  }
}
```

Can Apollo pass the variables internally or I just have to split the query into two for such case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. You'd have to run the two queries in sequence. What's preferable however is to define a different query that returns both the `name` and `parsedName` that you're looking for. Even better would be to extend the `description` to include a `parsedName` field and just write a resolver for that then you'd never need to run sequential queries.